# Helm jenkins/latest unable to run docker command

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed jenkins via helm to my cluster and added a freestyle project ( not pipeline ). It correctly boots up slaves & connects to the master and starts the build, however i'm getting the error:

```
ERROR: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/home/jenkins/workspace/MrSecurity.Proxy"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/home/jenkins/workspace/MrSecurity.Proxy"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

When I created the jenkins deploy I passed in:

```
  volumes:
  - type: HostPath
    secretName: /var/run/docker.sock
    mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
```

And in the jenkins UI i got the following settings.[image]

Could someone please help me on how to solve this. I figured it cant run docker because its docker-in-docker, however I can't find a solution to it, seems like I have tried everything..

Comment: Just mounting the socket isn't enough, you need the docker cli (or some plugin / library that's going to use the Docker API) in the image as well. Looks from the image that it's looking for (and missing) the docker cli.

Comment: I solved it by running a dind image for the container instead, however now i'm getting error: Step 1/17 : FROM node:9-alpine as deps
Error parsing reference: "node:9-alpine as deps" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

Comment: Do you have any clue?

Comment: What version of docker?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: seems its Container Runtime Version:  docker://1.13.1

Comment: That's very old, I would upgrade. It's also the reason why it's not recognizing the `FROM node:9-alpine as deps` syntax, as that didn't come in until version 17.06.